# workbench.action.toggleTabsVisibility Command is missing after 1.84.2 Update

Tags: visual-studio-code

At Visual Studio Code version 1.7x.x, I assigned a keyboard shortcut to hide tabs visibility. It looks like this:

```json
// keybindings.json

{
    "key": "ctrl+t ctrl+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleTabsVisibility"
}
```

Then updating to 1.84.2 shows `command 'workbench.action.toggleTabsVisibility' not found` when I try to use the keybinding. Is it removed or is there new command for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your GitHub issue (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/198151#issuecomment-1809708431):

> In the last update we changed the `workbench.editor.showTabs` setting
> from a boolean value to an enum (`multiple`, `single`, `none`). Due to this
> change we can't support the old command anymore, however, we added 3
> new commands:
>
> `workbench.action.showMultipleEditorTabs`
> `workbench.action.showEditorTab`
> `workbench.action.hideEditorTabs`
>
> This means you can create the same shortcut as you previously had.
> Mark has posted a good answer to your question on Stack Overflow. If
> you use his suggested keybinding, the behaviour should be identical to
> how it used to be.

If you are looking to toggle between showing a single tab and multiple tabs, try these keybindings:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+t ctrl+t",        // same keybinding as below, so it is a toggle
  "command": "workbench.action.hideEditorTabs",
  "when": "editorTabsVisible"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+t ctrl+t",        // same as above
  "command": "workbench.action.showMultipleEditorTabs",
  "when": "!editorTabsVisible"
}
```

These use a context clause to distinguish the two states.

Comment: Thanks sir. I also thought about the same thing, but `when` is the part that I didn't know. IMO this still maintain the same toggle functionality as before except for breadcrumbs is just different.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like roughly last month (the 1.84.0 update) these commands were renamed (and some commands were also added) looking at the Visual Studio Code repository commit history [here in commit `e47adcb`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/e47adcbf4bfdbe76aa6240d7186f2723d236d066#diff-68b7ff112ed282fedef1cd612c7e7c28b6159bf7aaa2680b7989b5ff64788befL493).

It looks like there are some new commands you instead need to use, namely `workbench.action.hideEditorTabs` to hide the editor tabs, and then `workbench.action.showMultipleEditorTabs` to reveal them again (there is also `workbench.action.showEditorTab` which will show a single tab as well, but if you want to show all tabs, then you can ignore that command).

Thus something like this in the JSON keyboard settings:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+t ctrl+q",
        "command": "workbench.action.hideEditorTabs"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+t ctrl+t",
        "command": "workbench.action.showEditorTab"
    }
]
```